# OOP class references

Tags: c#, oop

Rewritten:

```
namespace OOPattempt
{
    class Skeleton
    {
        public int hp = 50;
            public void Talking()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Im a skeleton");
        }
    }

    class Archer : Skeleton
    {
        public void StateHP()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My hp is {0}", hp);
        }
    }

    class Gaurd : Skeleton
    {
        public int attackDamage = 10;
    }
    class StrongArcher : Archer
    {
        public void StrongArchDamage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I do more damage then the weak skeleton");
        }
    }

    class WeakArcher : Archer
    {
        public void WeakArchDamage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I do less damage then a stronger skeleton");
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Skeleton skeleton = new Skeleton();
            Archer archer = new Archer();
            WeakArcher weakArcher = new WeakArcher();
            StrongArcher strongArcher = new StrongArcher();
            Gaurd gaurd = new Gaurd();

            skeleton.Talking();
            archer.StateHP();
            Console.WriteLine("Im a gaurd and my attack damage is {0}", gaurd.attackDamage);
            weakArcher.WeakArchDamage();
            strongArcher.StrongArchDamage();
        }
    }
}
```

Im wondering if there's a way to have to not call the reference for each class in the internal class to do the desired thing. So if I remove `Skeleton skeleton = new Skeleton();` I can't use the line `skeleton.Talking();`

Comment: See https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method, I'm not really sure what you're planning to do about calling the class to do the instructions. Wouldn't WeakArchDamage() require a *specific* WeakArcher? If you want a default instance, see Singleton pattern, if you want the system to handle multiple WeakArchers, you need a Manager pattern.

Comment: I stopped reading in the first paragraph of the question. It doesn't make sense _at all_. `static void Main` is _not_ a `class` it is a (static) method. Inside of it you are free to create instances of any class that allows you to do so. You are throwing around words you obviously have no clue about their meaning. So - and I don't mean to be offensive - I'd recommend you to go through some beginner's tutorial.

Comment: In real life you would store your NPCs in a database. So your game designer can specify that he wants 2 strong archers and one skeleton at some positions. I would recommend reading Eric lipperts [Wizards and warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) for an introduction to some of the common problems when creating classes.

Comment: You don't need to write it twice. You can either do `var sk = new Skeleton(); sk.Talking();`, or even `new Skelton().Talking()`, if you don't need the reference to the skeleton being created.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your Question:
No you can't.

Why?
With `Skeleton skeleton = new Skeleton();` you create a new Skeleton with the name skeleton and if you would not do that, the program doesn't now who has to `...Talking()`.

Imaging you want a army of Skeletons - every skeleton needs a name...

```
Skeleton elton = new Skeleton();
Skeleton andrew = new Skeleton();
Skeleton cherry = new Skeleton();
```

with elton.Talking() elton would talk and so on...

Comment: You can also get rid of one of the countless skeletons like `var skeleton = new Skeleton();` or `Skeleton skeleton = new();`